# Png and bmp images are not diplayed in SP2013 - 2010 mode

Tags: 2013

I have  a web part in SharePoint 2010 and recently migrated to SharePoint 2013. This web part is working fine in SharePoint 2010 server. However I am facing an issue when we migrated to SharePoint 2013 (in SharePoint 2010 mode).

About the web part:

This Web part reads images from picture library and displays in the in the web part.This Picture library contains files like .jpg, .png,.bmp.

**Issue:
In SharePoint 2013 (2010 mode), .png and .bmp format images are not shown.**

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default these file types are not included in SharePoint search.

You can add your own file types by going to Central Administration and:

Manage Service Applications => Search Service Application => File Types